# jquery multiple checkboxes - selector not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have tried to do a test:

```
var test = Array();

$('input[name=first_category[]]:checked').each(function()
{
    test.push($(this).val());
});

alert(test);
```

1. Check the last checkbox.
2. Refresh the page.
3. Alert should be empty (but is not empty, it shows me 4).

I have 5 categories and each category contains more than 10 checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I have updated my solution. 
[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/TGqz8/2/) for the updated solution.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="first_category[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="first_category[]" value="2" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="second_category[]" value="3" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="second_category[]" value="4" />
<br/>
<input type="button" value="check" id="btnCheck"/>

$("#btnCheck").live('click', function() {
    var test = [];
    $("input[name='first_category[]']:checked").each(function() {
        test.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(test);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I want is to alert only the checkboxes from first_category[].

Comment: A link to an external site is not an acceptable answer. I have copied your code from jsfiddle back into your answer. (pending peer review)